# static_cast between primitive references

Tags: c++, static-cast

Is using `static_cast` to convert from `const unsigned char&` to `const unsigned long long&` defined?

```
constexpr unsigned char arr[sizeof(unsigned long long)]{ 1 };
constexpr bool value = static_cast<const unsigned long long&>(arr[0]) == 1;
```

Throw in `int main(){}` and this compiles without error or warning on Coliru, Ideone, and VS2015. Is this actually safe, or is it unsafe but not required to give an error?

BONUS: I didn't expect that `arr[0]` would be a constant expression, but using `value` as a constant expression works without error. Is it because `arr` is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is covered by [expr.static.cast]/4 in C++14:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`. The effect of such an
>   explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

This defines your code as being equivalent to:

```
constexpr unsigned char arr[sizeof(unsigned long long)]{ 1 };

const unsigned long long &t (arr[0]);

constexpr bool value = (t == 1);
```

The second line is familiar now: initialization of a const reference from a value of different (non-reference-related) type is permitted under [dcl.init.ref]/5:

> If `T1` is a non-class type, a temporary of type *cv1 `T1`* is created and copy-initialized from the initializer expression. The reference is then bound to the temporary.

Answer (score 2):

<s>* It's undefined because you're using one type through a reference to another.
* You used a cast, so the compiler is supposed to trust you if it can perform that cast.
* It'll usually work the way you seem to expect except that I doubt value will be true on most architectures.</s>

And actually I think what happens here is that the const& you cast to gets bound to a temporary, or would if it happened at run time.  So yeah, you should get `1` from the value.  The `char` 1 will be copied into an `unsigned long long` and the const& will bind to that.  It won't bind to the array you made I don't think.  This would be totally safe and you can ignore most of the above.

You could test this thought a bit, possibly, by trying to convert to an lvalue.  You'd have to not have your data be `constexpr` though.

http://ideone.com/TxYose

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten I can't alias backwards like I did. To clarify, is using `static_cast` to create a reference UB?

Comment: I don't believe it is, but using that reference I believe is.

Comment: @JamesRoot - I think I was mistaken about what would happen.  I think you bind to a temporary.

Comment: I just tested it and you are correct, it constructs a temporary and binds to it.